# Why is my gnu file not read?

Tags: gnuplot

I want to plot some data with gnuplot. The input to gnuplot is generated using a script. The input for gnuplot that comes out of my script looks something like this:

```
set term aqua
set hidden3d
set xlabel 'L*'
set ylabel 'a*'
set zlabel 'b*'
set xrange [0:100]
set yrange [-165:165]
set zrange [-135:145]
splot '-' using 1:2:3:4 notitle with points pt 1 ps 1.5 lc rgb variable, '/Users/jnevens/Babel2/.tmp/borders-46.gnu' notitle with lines
51.036446 86.55453 -70.64755 0xAA1DF0
65.64255 -12.33849 -7.135427 0x8AA5AA
72.188156 14.840424 67.7636 0xD6A339
83.96458 -97.23782 73.87116 0x72F747
90.79163 -1.0941625 40.725815 0xF6E299
e
```

The error I get is

```
warning: Cannot find or open file "/Users/jnevens/Babel2/.tmp/borders-46.gnu"
```

However, I do not know what might be wrong with this file. The contents of `borders-46.gnu` looks like this:

```
51.036446 86.55453 -70.64755 
65.64255 -12.33849 -7.135427 
72.188156 14.840424 67.7636 
83.96458 -97.23782 73.87116 
90.79163 -1.0941625 40.725815
```

How can I find out what is wrong? How can I fix this?

Comment: The only thing I can think is a problem with the file path, or maybe permissions. I copied your script and data file to the same directory and everything ran smoothly.

Comment: @ViniciusPlacco My problem was indeed the file path. My script stores files as `borders-xx` while the gnuplot script looks for files using `borders-xx.gnu`. This causes the file not to be found.

Comment: Well, I'm glad it was a simple thing then!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when i tried to run mygnucode.plt file, using mydata.txt file.

So I had to rename my "mydata" file to "mydata.txt". As this might be the reason, why it was not working for you.

I did the same, and it worked for me.